# Is it possible to change all instances of a css color in Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Within a website I'm managing, it's necessary to see how a color change affects the site on a global level.

I know that I can use the inspector, find the element, and change the css color there and it will change for that one instance, but is it possible to make a color switch globally? So, for example, #000 is used everywhere #fff is?

It's not possible to a find and replace in all of the css files / javascript files, so trying to do this temporarily through Chrome Developer Tools / Inspector (or any other browser tools, Firefox, too).

Comment: Questions about [coding](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic for this site, and this will likely also lead to [recommendations](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for external resources, which are also considered off-topic. You might consider using a server-side script to change the CSS on-the-fly, or include CSS rules with [the !important exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) specified to override them.